# Automatically open html links in new tab

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html document with 100 html-links. When I open the document in a browser I want all the links in the document to open automatically in 100 different tabs in the same browser. Alternatively I want to do this some other way with the terminal in OS X or with cmd.exe in Windows. This is just for data collection and not web development.

Comment: so loop over the links and call window.open or click on them.

Comment: My code is plain html with links. Now I am pressing Ctrl on Windows and clicking on all the links. But I am repeating the process with 100 and 100 links and want to automate the process.

Comment: Putting window.open in front of all the links worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @Digital_Dog If this solution worked for you, can you please mark my answer as selected?

Comment: @Emre Bolat. Sure!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a simple Javascript function.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{
window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');
window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','_blank');
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qxqwcqus/) to test the effect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might get the effect you are after using the base tag in the head.

```
<head><base target="_blank"></head>
```